# Rest Service to read a zip file in a client

Tags: cxf, jax-rs

I am trying to implement a rest service that reads a zip file. A client calls this service, and builds the zip file from the response. I have this for my service:

```
@Produces({ "application/zip" })
@GET
@Path("/fetchZip")
public Response getZip() {
try {
    InputStream theFile = new FileInputStream("test.zip");
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(theFile);
    return Response.ok(zis).build();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}
```

Can anyone let me know if this is the right way to do it?

Comment: Does this approach work? Probably you will have to indicate the content-type that you are returning.

Comment: I tried adding the content-type, but that did not seem to work either

Comment: Can you post the request that you are doing and the error you get?

Comment: This is my client code
     HttpGet request = new         HttpGet("http://localhost:3000/myservice/fetchZip");
     request.addHeader(new BasicHeader("Accept", "application/zip"));
     HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
     InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
     
     ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(is);

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: I am not able to save it back as a zip file on the client. There's no error as such, but I am not able to figure out a way to save that file back as a zip

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, reading from the `InputStream` of the response and writing into `FileOutputstream` for the file:

```
     URL url = new URL("YOUR_URL");
     HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     conn.setDoOutput(true);
     conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
     conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
     if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("C:/yourFile.zip");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
           output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        output.close();
     } 
     conn.disconnect();
```

Comment: I tried that as well, but when I tried to open the zip file, it said it's damaged